# When I enter 0 I get the message "0 has already been entered" 6 times

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and have a homework assignment where I'm to use a one-dimensional six-element vector to the solve a problem. Whole numbers from 10 to 101. 
I set it up so if I enter 0 it says "0 is out of bounds" and will say "0 has already been entered. All other numbers not in the above scope will print the message once. However for 0 I get it the message six times. I'm just wondering what I'm missing here. The program otherwise works great. TIA!!

After running it and entering 0 I get

```
0 is out of bounds
0 has been entered
0 has been entered
0 has been entered
etc.
please enter a number
```

I have 3 separate files for the homework assignment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

Selection::Selection()
{

}
bool Selection::checknumber(int n) const
{
    if (n < 10 || n > 101)
    {
        cerr << "\nNumber\n" << n << " is out of bounds.\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
bool Selection::checkvector(const vector<int> &v, int n)
{
    bool check = true;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < v.size(); ++j)
    {
        if (n == v[j])
        {
            cerr << "\nNumber " << n << " has already been entered.\n";
            check = false;
        }
    }
    return check;
}
void Selection::displayvector(vector<int> &v) const
{
    cout << "\nThe numbers in the vector are: ";
    for (int item : v)
    {
        cout << item << " ";
    }
}
void Selection::menu()
{
    const size_t size = 6;
    vector<int>name(size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i)
    {
        int number = 40;
        bool cont = false;
        while (cont == false)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a number:\n";
            cin >> number;
            bool cont1 = checknumber(number);
            bool cont2 = checkvector(name, number);
            if (cont1 == false || cont2 == false)
            {
                cont = false;
            }
            else
                cont = true;
        }
        name[i] = number;

    }
    sort(name.begin(), name.end());
    displayvector(name);

    int input = 10;
    while (input >= 0)
    {
        bool position = false;
        cout << "\nPlease enter a number to search in vector OR a negative number to exit: ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input < 0)
            break;
        bool found = binary_search(name.begin(), name.end(), input);
        cout << endl << input << (found ? " was " : " was not ") << "found in the vector";
    }
    cout << "\n\nGoodbye\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) with a size like you do in the following line

```
std::vector<int> name(size);
```

All the elements in that `vector` will be default-initialized depending on the type used. In this case, you used an `int` so all the elements will be `0`.

Since you never change those elements, when you call

```
checkvector(name, number);
```

And pass in `0` (as `number`), it matches all the elements in the `vector`.

You will need to give your `vector` different default values, or disallow passing in `0`. Alternatively, you could just construct an empty `vector` and as unique numbers are passed in you can add them to your `vector`:

```
bool Selection::checkvector(const vector<int> &v, int n)
{
    // Check if our vector contains this number.
    if (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), n) != v.end())
    {
        // n was found in v
        cerr << "\nNumber " << n << " has already been entered.\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // n was not found, so add it. This will increase the vector's size by 1.
        v.push_back(n);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Instead of looping over every element, I'm using [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) to search the container for `n`.

Comment: Okay that explains it, thank you for the easy to understand explanation.